# Does Impending Doom decreases Exploding Palm's DPS?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-monk

The skill description of [Exploding Palm](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/class/monk/active/exploding-palm) reads:

> Cause a target to Bleed for 745% weapon damage as Physical over 9 seconds.

The description of its Impending Doom rune reads:

> Increases the duration of the Bleed effect to deal 745% weapon damage as Physical over 15 seconds.

If the rune changes the skill to do the same damage over more time, doesn't it effectively *decrease* the skill's DPS? And if so, what is the benefit of this rune? Just to have a bigger time window for the explosion to take effect?

Comment: Great question, been wondering the same myself, but rather suspected an ill formulated tooltip than 1/2 dps  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does the same damage. You're correct, the 'point' such as it is, is to provide a larger window of time in which to trigger the explosion, which makes it a very effective source of AE damage. 30% of a targets max health can be... substantial, if it's the right target.